# TypeScript does not warn for extra props

Tags: typescript

given the following snippet TS does not warn that I have an extra option on my Payload.

```js
interface Payload {
  option1: string;
  option2: string;
  option3: string;
  option4: number[];
}

export const myFunction = {
  send: async (payload: Payload) => {
      console.log(payload)
  },
};

const payload = {
    option1: 'option1',
    option2: 'option1',
    option3: 'option1',
    option4: [1,2,3],
    option5: 'option1',
};

myFunction.send(payload);
```

I can fix this a few ways:

```js
const payload: Payload = {
    option1: 'option1',
    option2: 'option1',
    option3: 'option1',
    option4: [1,2,3],
    option5: 'option1',
};
```

or

```js
myFunction.send({
    option1: 'option1',
    option2: 'option1',
    option3: 'option1',
    option4: [1,2,3],
    option5: 'option1',
});
```

I kinda get it why it works this way, but unsure of the proper reason. This has also been giving us some false sense of security so would be good if I could fix this in our codebase.

[TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwJ4BsD2cAmyA3gLABQyyOADmMDiAIwBcyAzmFKAOYDc5lGnQYAmVhy4g+AqrXogAzOM49+FWcJAAWViACuAWwBG0ANoBdNQF9y5CAA9qOKGGQIGHZAYwAxPSARNZABeYhk2CBB8Vjg2DADkAApqTFwCVnRsPHwAShCAPjD1Skp3EDYcLAgAOlxuZNTsnJkrABpyKzVyAHpu5B9ge2RGZABaZAJCMAxqFDAcNw8wVgADMs8UrPS0RoIQ4hXydddNtMJQ0mKNeRZkAHIhG7v2q8fRVge5BkZnmUEvxQfN5MX6vAE6ZCmRitEStBTmF4la4MACsQIBPxenVsZG8fgCmmqESiDS2uS6ZF6-UGyBEYwm+EIOCMACsIIFkKAOBA9jgYJzXCYeJyQBNkAA3OBQch4-yBeREyL4RKXJHA26fTSYv7IkBie7q0FqgFKA0Yo0lYEQqEwuEInXAtFmrWgqw5NRAA)

Comment: "Excess property checks" are only applied when the object is _only_ accessible through the relevant interface. If you let the type of `payload` be inferred, how's the compiler supposed to know you think `option5` is excessive? Why would it matter to receivers of `Payload`s whether or not there are additional properties that _they can't access_? This is all part of the structural (rather than nominal) typing system - `payload` _is_ compatible with the `Payload` interface, despite the extra properties.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe for teaching me the correct phrase. This makes so much more sense now that I've read it.!

Comment: See the linked question and answer for more information.  There's really nothing you can do to prohibit excess properties, so ideally your code shouldn't depend on their absence.  You can discourage them (as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wRGYXN)) but it's not foolproof.